# Reflection error when using F# sprintf "%A" on Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, f#, windows-phone

I have a set of F# record types like this:

```
type Course =
    { Id : int
      Title : string
      Instructor : string
      Duration : string
      StartDate : string
      IconUrl : string
      Url : string 
      LectureSections : LectureSection list }

and LectureSection =
    { Title : string
      Completed : bool
      Lectures : Lecture list }

and Lecture = 
    { Title : string
      VideoUrl : string }
```

and at some point I call

```
sprintf "%A" course
```

where course is an instance of the Course record

On a regular .NET project this works fine, but on a Windows Phone 7.1 / Silverlight 4 F# project (I'm using Daniel Mohl's templates), I get this error:

```
Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.
```

The problem seems to be the lists. Does anyone know of any way around this problem?

Comment: An obvious workaround is to override `ToString()` member and use `sprintf "%O"` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The templates should come with a custom built FSharp.Core.dll that disable features that are not available on Windows Phone. Are you sure you are compiling against this dll, and not the Windows PC one?

I had similar problems with Xbox360 and XNA. The F# team sent me a dll suitable for use for the Xbox360, along with some brief instructions on the settings used to build the dll.

> Here is the propertygroup we've used to compile FSharp.Core:

```
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='Xbox360\CompactFramework\3.7'">
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <TargetFrameworkProfile>Client</TargetFrameworkProfile>
   <XnaFrameworkVersion>v4.0</XnaFrameworkVersion>
   <XnaPlatform>Xbox 360</XnaPlatform>
   <XnaProfile>HiDef</XnaProfile>
   <XnaCrossPlatformGroupID>a8d70e6b-9a75-4aec-80f8-62cf373f7368</XnaCrossPlatformGroupID>
   <XnaOutputType>Game</XnaOutputType>
   <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>
   <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants);FX_NO_ARRAY_LONG_LENGTH;FX_NO_DEBUG_PROXIES;FX_NO_EXIT;FX_FSLIB_IOBSERVABLE;FX_NO_WEB_CLIENT;FX_NO_WEB_REQUESTS;FX_NO_CHAR_PARSE;FX_NO_DEFAULT_DEPENDENCY_TYPE;FX_SIMPLE_SECURITY_PERMISSIONS;FX_NO_TRUNCATE;FX_NO_CULTURE_INFO_ARGS;FX_NO_REFLECTION_MODULE_HANDLES;FX_NO_OPERATION_CANCELLED;FX_NO_TO_LOWER_INVARIANT;FX_NO_EXIT_CONTEXT_FLAGS;FX_NO_BASED_ARRAYS;FX_NO_DOUBLE_BIT_CONVERTER;FX_NO_BINARY_SERIALIZATION;FX_NO_ASCII_ENCODING;FX_NO_DEFAULT_ENCODING;FX_NO_FILE_OPTIONS;FX_NO_NONBLOCK_IO;FX_NO_COMMAND_LINE_ARGS;FX_NO_ENVIRONMENT;FX_NO_PROCESS_START;FX_NO_APP_DOMAINS;FX_NO_PROCESS_DIAGNOSTICS;FX_FSLIB_STRUCTURAL_EQUALITY;FX_FSLIB_LAZY;FX_FSLIB_TUPLE;FX_NO_REFLECTION_EMIT</DefineConstants>
   <Tailcalls>false</Tailcalls>
   <!-- It would be better to use MSBuild resolution here, but the TargetFrameworkIdentifier etc. aren't set up quite correctly as yet -->
   <OtherFlags>$(OtherFlags) --simpleresolution -r:"C:\Program Files\Microsoft XNA\XNA Game Studio\v4.0\References\Xbox360\mscorlib.dll"</OtherFlags>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

> and the new .targets we use:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\XNA Game Studio\Microsoft.Xna.GameStudio.targets" Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='Xbox360\CompactFramework\3.7'"/>
```

The dll they sent me was working fine, and I never had to use these instructions, but they might be useful to someone who wants to build an FSharp.Core.dll for a new platform. Note in particular the `DefineConstants` part.

Comment: I'm linking to the custom built FSharp.Core.dll that comes in the template. I can try to recompile FSharp.Core from source to see if it solves the problem. There's also two extra files on the template - FSharp.Core.optdata and FSharp.Core.sigdata - I'm not sure what they are and if I need to also regenerate them or not

Comment: Maybe a bug in the handling of %A in FSharp.Core? If you search for the error message, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843042/invoking-a-method-of-a-generic-class shows up. People who forget the call to `MakeGenericType` get this error.

Comment: I replaced the FSharp.Core file that comes in the template by the one that comes in the [F# April 2011 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11100) in the WindowsPhone7\Silverlight\4.0\bin folder, and while it solved [another problem I was having](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486311/f-quotations-on-windows-phone/10558374), I still get this exception on %A