# F# quotations on Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, f#, windows-phone

I'm using Daniel Mohl's F# templates for Windows phone, but it seems the bundled FSharp.Core doesn't have some of the quotations code. I'm trying to port this code from regular .NET:

```
open System.ComponentModel
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns

[<AbstractClass>]
type ViewModelBase() =

    let propertyChanged = new Event<_, _>()

    let toPropName expr =
        match expr with
        | PropertyGet(a, b, list) -> b.Name
        | _ -> failwith "Unsupported: " + expr.ToString()

    interface INotifyPropertyChanged with
        [<CLIEvent>]
        member x.PropertyChanged = propertyChanged.Publish

    member x.NotityPropertyChanged expr =
        propertyChanged.Trigger(x, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(toPropName expr))
```

But the compiler complaints about Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations.Patterns and PropertyGet. It seems it doesn't even know the Expr type.
Any idea on how to solve this?

Comment: I know it's not an answer but the docs say this should be supported from Silverlight 3 up so this seems as if it may be a bug.  You may want to send it to fsbugs at microsoft dot com and see what sort of response they have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced the FSharp.Core file that comes in the template by the one that comes in the [F# April 2011 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11100) in the WindowsPhone7\Silverlight\4.0\bin folder, and with this version it now compiles fine

Answer (score 1):

I've compared FSharp.Core.dll from Template you've mentiond and those one which is referenced if you create a F# Silverlight library with .Net Reflector and they are different! :) Thouse one which added to template's dependencies folder doesn't have Quotations.

So my first two thoughts is either add F# SCL and create your view model there or not to use this template at all. But I actually like this template or how it looks at least... so thanks you for the mentioning it anyway :)